# JVM created by JNI does not use classpath specified

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Here is my code snippet:

```c
JavaVMOption options[MAX_OPTS];
vm_args.version  = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
vm_args.nOptions = 0;
vm_args.options = options;

char* class_path = getenv("CLASSPATH");
if (class_path) {
    char path[4096];
    sprintf(path, "-Djava.class.path=%s", class_path);
    options[vm_args.nOptions++].optionString = path;
}
...
res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
...
jclass          cls;
jmethodID       mid;

cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, class);
if (cls == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to find Main class\n");
    return 1;
}
```

It failed to find the class on Debian10, but it works on Ubuntu all series versions.

I install `openjdk-11-jdk` on both Linux.

I also try to install the official version instead: https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.deb, but on Debian10, it does not work too.

I use `strace` to check what happens under the hood. I found on Debian10, it does not look up the classpath I set, but Ubuntu does!

So weird, is there something special on Debian10?

Comment: The compiler is free to reuse the memory for that `path` variable once it goes out of scope. Use `asprintf` or move the declaration of `path` up one level.

Comment: Your code is also vulnerable to a stack-overflow attack from a `CLASSPATH` environment variable long enough to overflow the buffer you provided.  Either use `asprintf()` as @Botje recommended or switch to `snprintf()`.

Comment: yes, I change my code to fix it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje) points out:

> The compiler is free to reuse the memory for that path variable once it goes out of scope. Use asprintf or move the declaration of path up one level.

The issue gets solved.
Thank you, Botje.